# AWS CDK Number Parameter as Integer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, floating-point, integer, aws-cdk

I'm using the AWS CDK and I'm struggling with the number parameter. The documentation says that numbers can be either an int or a float. Here's how a number parameter is setup in the code:

```
number_parameter = CfnParameter(self, "number_parameter", type="Number",
                   description="Number Parameter")
```

And here's how I'm accessing the value:

```
number_parameter.value_as_number
```

The problem I'm running into, is that whenever I use cdk synth, it's assuming that this parameter is a float. I know this because I'm trying to use the parameter in functions that only accept integers, not floats, which is causing an error. I also cannot convert it to an integer using the int() operator, because I get an error that it's too large to convert to an integer.

How do I specify that I only want integers, not floats, for this parameter? Or is there some other way I can convert it to an integer, even though I can't control how the CDK initializes this value?

Comment: maybe can use a regex with a string input? like `[0-9]+` or something?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use a regex as a parameter type. That's also part of the problem, the docs only show one simple string example.

Comment: Turns out you can use regex, but I'm not able to convert the string to an int still. Is there seriously not a way to specify that it's an int? How are you supposed to use this number parameter if you can't specify whether it's an int or a float?

Comment: this might be a little roundabout and honestly a bit of a reach, but have you looked into using `Fn::Transform`? my thought is you could pair that with something like `Fn::FindInMap` to get the numeric value of a number in string format.

Comment: also, what do you mean that the number is too large to convert using `int()`? I might be wrong but i don't think you'd normally run into such an issue, unless your number is insanely large - like `int('9' * 1000000)` for example.

Comment: kind of a follow up, but have you tried with keeping it as a string parameter (regex) but with using int() operator to get the numeric value when needed?

Comment: I tried the regex solution with a String type parameter, but it didn't like me trying to convert it to an int. I don't think this is actually an issue though, I'm getting the issue when trying to run cdk synth. I found out that parameters don't work correctly through cdk synth, so I think this will work just fine as a number parameter when I use cdk deploy, but I'll have to get back to you on that.

Comment: Looks like I was correct that it works fine at deploy time. It also looks like you can't actually use CDK parameter values in the code, like say an if statement or a function. So, what I'm trying to do here isn't really how CDK parameters are supposed to be used. Now I'm wondering if there is a way to pass in arguments that can be used in the code with a cdk command (especially since this argument isn't actually being used in any AWS resources, it's just being used to generate something used in an AWS resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this question was just me misunderstanding how the AWS CDK actually works. I was trying to use CDK parameters in a way that is not supported. There were 2 issues with what I was trying to do:

1. Parameters can only be resolved at runtime. I was trying to set them using cdk synth. Upon actually deploying my solution, I was able to input an integer parameter fine.
2. Parameters cannot be used in CDK code. So, you cannot set a parameter to 1 and then use it in a function or a statement in the code. You can only use it to set values in the resulting CloudFormation template.